# Ruby crash on server

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, server

After 10 years my setup has started crashing every couple of weeks. The error I receive is below. The company that created the system has gone under and I do not have clue where to start getting this fixed. Any ideas would a great help.

```
The error encountered was: Errno::ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused - connect(2) 

Backtrace:
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `initialize'

/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `open'

/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `connect'

/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:53:in `timeout'

/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:101:in `timeout'

/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `connect'

/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:553:in `do_start'

/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:542:in `start'

/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:440:in `start'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/bundler/gems/Show-Control-b7149704e299/lib/show_control/api/client.rb:122:in `request'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/bundler/gems/Show-Control-b7149704e299/lib/show_control/api/client.rb:105:in `get'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/bundler/gems/Show-Control-b7149704e299/lib/show_control/api/client.rb:73:in `find_all'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/bundler/gems/Show-Control-b7149704e299/lib/show_control/api/client.rb:38:in `find_all_templates'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/app/controllers/admin/scheduler/templates_controller.rb:4:in `index'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150:in `process_action'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11:in `process_action'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `process_action'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:436:in `_run__577361292__process_action__199225275__callbacks'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:410:in `send'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:410:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94:in `send'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94:in `run_callbacks'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:119:in `process'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:41:in `process'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:138:in `dispatch'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:178:in `action'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `call'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `dispatch'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:27:in `call'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148:in `call'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93:in `recognize'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:82:in `optimized_each'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92:in `recognize'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139:in `call'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:493:in `call'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/hoptoad_notifier-2.3.12/lib/hoptoad_notifier/rack.rb:27:in `call'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/haml-3.0.25/lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:41:in `call'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/warden-1.0.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/warden-1.0.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/warden-1.0.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in `call'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in `call'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/plugins/latitude/lib/latitude/middleware/flash_session_cookie_middleware.rb:18:in `call'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:302:in `call'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `call'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:28:in `cache'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in `cache'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:354:in `call'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in `call'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:416:in `_run_call_callbacks'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-contrib-1.1.0/lib/rack/contrib/sendfile.rb:105:in `call'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-contrib-1.1.0/lib/rack/contrib/runtime.rb:18:in `call'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'

/opt/www/apps/server.XXXXXXX.lan/releases/20111223105109/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'

/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.5/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:96:in `process_request'

/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.5/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:513:in `accept_and_process_next_request'

/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.5/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:274:in `main_loop'

/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.5/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:205:in `start_request_handler'

/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.5/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:170:in `send'

/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.5/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:170:in `handle_spawn_application'

/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.5/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:479:in `safe_fork'

/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.5/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:165:in `handle_spawn_application'

/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.5/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'

/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.5/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'

/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.5/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'

/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.5/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'

/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.5/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:128:in `start'

/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.5/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:253:in `spawn_rack_application'

/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.5/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'

/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.5/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in `spawn_rack_application'

/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.5/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `synchronize'

/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.5/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'

/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.5/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:244:in `spawn_rack_application'

/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.5/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:137:in `spawn_application'

/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.5/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'

/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.5/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'

/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.5/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'

/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.5/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'

/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.5/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99

Back
```

Comment: You will find an answer in
`app/controllers/admin/scheduler/templates_controller.rb` Line 4

Comment: It seems that your server is making a request to another service and the connection is being refused. If this is happening every other week, try identifying the services and what is happening at that moment to locate the root cause.